# mix atomic and non atomic variables and caches

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic

Let's say we have this piece of code that it is correct (I hope at least) :

```
std::atomic<int> a;
std::atomic<bool> ready{false};
void threadA() {
    a.store(666, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    ready.store(true, std::memory_order_release);
}

void threadB() {
    while(!ready.load(std::memory_order_acquire));
    process(a.load(std::memory_order_relaxed));
}
```

My question is : In the case you are using a `int a;` instead of `std::atomic<int> a;`, it is correct as well? Or is there a problem of cache flushing / invalidation?

Comment: If you have to ask... use sequential consistency. Unless heavily commented and encapsulated, even if you understand what you're doing, the guy maintaining your code will not.

Comment: It is not really for a specific usecase. It is more more for theory than something else ;).
However, will this code work with sequential consistency ?

Comment: It looks fine to me. I would encourage you to watch the lecture called "atomic weapons". It all made sense to me after that.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c1gO9aB9nbs

Comment: Classic "complete" pattern, where atomic `ready` variable plays role of a flag, which protects setting of other variables. Variables protected by this mechanism needn't to be atomic. (That is, yes, you may use `int a;`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether or not this is a good idea, as an example, your code is fine..

You may replace the atomic type of `a` with a regular `int` (or any type for that matter).
The C++ standard supports your case with the following phrase (§ 1.10.1-6):

> Certain library calls synchronize with other library calls performed by another thread. For example, an atomic store-release synchronizes with a load-acquire that takes its value from the store

Since `threadB` loads the value of `ready` stored by `threadA` (it is waiting for it in a loop), the *synchronizes-with* relationship is established.
Therefore, `a.load()` observes the memory effects of `a.store()`.  Another way to say this is that `a.store()` *happens-before* `a.load()`

Comment: Yeah, but my question was more about : is it correct to replace the atomic variable by a non atomic one. And you answered at the beginning ;)